# Passing Japanese (non-Latin) URLs in Facebook "like" button URL fails

Tags: javascript, facebook, urlencode

I think this is a URL encoding problem and not a bug in Facebook, but I'm really not sure.

This URL fails on the Like button: `http://www.thefraser.com/2010/11/%E5%8B%95%E7%89%A9%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AE%E6%88%A6%E3%81%84`

But this one works: `http://www.thefraser.com/2010/11/carlos`

What worries me is that the former URL fails in the [Like button generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) thing on Facebook, giving me an error saying that there is no fanpage at the given URL.

I think the like button generator is glitched in the same way that my URL encoding is. I highly doubt that Facebook's like button itself is broken, since then everyone with non-English URLs would be complaining.

On the other hand, the same URL encoding for the same URL works for Twitter, so... hmm...

Any ideas for a workaround URL encoding? This one I'm using right now is `Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.encodeURI()`, which in theory behaves the same way as the JavaScript encodeURI function.

Strange question, I know, but any help would be appreciated. I'm on the verge of eating my cat alive.

**Edit:** other Japanese URLs, like this one:

`http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B%E3%82%8A`

don't fail with the Like button generator. Bahhh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, [it's a bug](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=82312).

> Hello,
>
> Please file a bug for this issue in
>   bugzilla (or subscribe to an existing
>   bug and add your information to it).
>   Best practice is to link back to the
>   bug in the originating forum thread to
>   help fellow developers and Facebook
>   engineers track the conversation and
>   provide follow-up.
>
> Make sure your bug includes sample
>   code and solid reproduction steps.
>
> Thanks,  Matt Trainer

Great. Their Bugzilla is also giving me an HTTP/500.

Answer (score 0):

I look into the source code of the given page, it seems your URL has been escaped twice in the source code:

line 125 (`%E5` has been converted into `%25E5`):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.thefraser.com/2010/11/%25E5%258B%2595%25E7%2589%25A9%25E3%2581%25A8%25E3%2581%25AE%25E6%2588%25A6%25E3%2581%2584&layout=standard ...
```

Are you using PHP? Double check the code that generate this line. Post it here if unsure.

Comment: Hmm tried getting rid of the second encoding; didn't work. I think it's necessary because it's a URL within a URL, and that %25E5 stuff is Unicode. In the browser's URL bar the URL is supposed to show up as `http://www.thefraser.com/2010/11/動物との戦い`.